# How can I load SVG dynamically in Extjs 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to load svg content dynamically, Extjs 4. The webpage is a live flight tracker, I need to draw the path of an airplane, so I need to update the SVG path dynamically. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieve this using templates:

```
svgIconTpl = new Ext.XTemplate (
    '<span class="tag-icon-field-item">',
        '<svg version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 40 40">',
            '<path fill="#eeeeee" stroke="none" d="{path}"></path>',
        '</svg>',
    '</span>'
);
```

And then:

```
svgIconTpl.apply({
    path: "[Whatever's your path]"
});
```